# Getting location of section of sprite

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I'm using IOS7's sprite kit and using *NSSpriteNode*  with default anchor of (.5, .5) [center]. The sprite will be rotating around a lot, is there a way to get the location relative to the anchor point? Like, if I'm looking for the sprites top-center anchorpoint of (.5,1)  or bottom-center (.5, 0)? This way I can always get the same location of a part of a sprite however it is rotated?

```
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ship.png"];
self.player.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 1);
CGPoint p = [self.player convertPoint:self.player.position toNode:self]];
NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f", p.x, p.y);
self.player.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 0);
CGPoint p = [self.player convertPoint:self.player.position toNode:self]];
NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f", p.x, p.y);
```

This ends up yielding the same point even though I'm changing my anchor point to be different parts.  I know this is a bad idea to change the anchor point, but trying to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I'd like a method something like:

```
CGPoint imageTopLoc = [self.player getLocationUsingAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(.5, 1)];
CGPoint imageBottomLoc = [self.player getLocationUsingAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(.5, 0)];
// calculate vector of direction between of two points... (next)
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Looks like I don't even need to deal with the anchor point, I should be able to translate from a "point" in one coordinate system (i.e., my node's coordinates system) to my scene's coordinate system, something like this:          CGPoint positionInScene = [node convertPoint:CGPointMake(0,10) toNode:node.scene];
But I'm not getting the expected results... :(

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the coordinates / touch point inside a node, regardless of the node's rotation. (It's based upon the SpriteKit Game template.)

Is that what you are looking for?

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        SKSpriteNode *ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        ship.name = @"ship";
        ship.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        ship.zRotation = M_PI * 0.5;
        [self addChild:ship];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *ship = [self childNodeWithName:@"ship"];

        CGPoint p = [self convertPoint:location toNode:ship];
        NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f", p.x, p.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the convertPoint was definitely the trick...   My code ended up being [self.player convertPoint:CGPointMake(1,self.player.size.height/2).   There were a lot of things that threw me off (newbie stuff).

Comment: First, I was calling this before I added the player to the scene, so it didn't have parent coordinate system to reference.   Second, even when I did call it, I had some code that would draw a line right at the point that I expected it to be in the spritenode (as I was testing to verify things), but it was always not quite were I expected it to be.   This ended up having to do with the player.physicsBody that would literally move my line because two masses took the same space... Anyhow, looks like I can move past this problem now, suggestions very appreciated!   Thanks.   Chris